# Proper shell execution in PHP

Tags: php, proc-open, k2f

## The problem

I was using a function that made use of `proc_open()` to invoke shell commands. It seems the way I was doing STDIO was wrong and sometimes caused PHP or the target command to lock up. This is the original code:

```
function execute($cmd, $stdin=null){
    $proc=proc_open($cmd,array(0=>array('pipe','r'),1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0],$stdin);                fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);  fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);  fclose($pipes[2]);
    return array( 'stdout'=>$stdout, 'stderr'=>$stderr, 'return'=>proc_close($proc) );
}
```

It works *most of the time*, but that is not enough, I want to make it work always.

The issue lies in `stream_get_contents()` locking up if the STDIO buffers exceed 4k of data.

## Test Case

```
function out($data){
    file_put_contents('php://stdout',$data);
}
function err($data){
    file_put_contents('php://stderr',$data);
}
if(isset($argc)){
    // RUN CLI TESTCASE
    out(str_repeat('o',1030);
    err(str_repeat('e',1030);
    out(str_repeat('O',1030);
    err(str_repeat('E',1030);
    die(128); // to test return error code
}else{
    // RUN EXECUTION TEST CASE
    $res=execute('php -f '.escapeshellarg(__FILE__));
}
```

We output a string twice to STDERR and STDOUT with the combined length of 4120 bytes (exceeding 4k). This causes PHP to lock up on both sides.

## Solution

Apparently, `stream_select()` is the way to go. I have the following code:

```
function execute($cmd,$stdin=null,$timeout=20000){
    $proc=proc_open($cmd,array(0=>array('pipe','r'),1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
    $write  = array($pipes[0]);
    $read   = array($pipes[1], $pipes[2]);
    $except = null;
    $stdout = '';
    $stderr = '';
    while($r = stream_select($read, $write, $except, null, $timeout)){
        foreach($read as $stream){

            // handle STDOUT
            if($stream===$pipes[1])
/*...*/         $stdout.=stream_get_contents($stream);

            // handle STDERR
            if($stream===$pipes[2])
/*...*/         $stderr.=stream_get_contents($stream);
        }

        // Handle STDIN (???)
        if(isset($write[0])) ;

// the following code is temporary
$n=isset($n) ? $n+1 : 0; if($n>10)break; // break while loop after 10 iterations

    }
}
```

**The only remaining piece of the puzzle is handling STDIN (see the line marked `(???)`).**
I figured out STDIN must be supplied by whatever is calling my function, `execute()`. But what if I don't want to use STDIN at all? In my testcase, above, I didn't ask for input, yet I'm supposed to do something to STDIN.

That said, **the above approach still freezes** at `stream_get_contents()`. I'm quite unsure what to do/try next.

## Credits

The solution was suggested by Jakob Truelsen, as well as discovering the original issue. The 4k tip was also his idea. Prior to this I was puzzled as to why the function was working fine (didn't know it all depended on buffer size).

Comment: If you don't plan on sending any data, you don't need to do anything with STDIN at all.  Like `$except`, you could just set `$write` to be null.

Comment: @Zoredache But my problem isn't with STDIN, but STDOUT. Also, this is the same reason I told Jay (below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, seems a year passed and forgot this thing is still pending!

However, I wrapped up this mess in a nice PHP class which you can find [on Github](https://github.com/uuf6429/InterExec).

The main remaining problem is that reading STDERR causes the PHP script to block, so it has been disabled.

On the bright side, thanks to events and some nice coding (I hope!), one can actually interact with the process being executed (hence the class name, `InterExec`). So you can have bot-style behavior in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed this note in the PHP manual for stream_select():

> When stream_select() returns, the arrays read, write and except are modified to indicate which stream resource(s) actually changed status.

You need to re-create the arrays before calling stream_select() each time.

Depending on the process you're opening, this may be why your example still blocks.

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as I get some time, but it is indeed a plausible explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while($r = stream_select($read, $write, $except, null, $timeout)){
```

As far as I know this will set $r to the number of changed streams, which may be 0 and the loop would no longer continue. I would personally recode this as described in the PHP manual:

```
while(false !== ($r = stream_select($read, $write, $except, null, $timeout))){
```

As far as your STDIN is concerned if your process is not interactive then the STDIN may not be necessary. What is the process you are executing?

Comment: This is a general function. I'd like to support STDIN for the sake of users that might want to use STDIN. :). As to $r being 0, it doesn't do much of a difference to me. It still gets stuck at stream_get_contents().

Comment: have you tried to see what it will accept? For example, a process like telnet you could open and then pass an 'o' followed by a newline and then an address x.x.x.x:xx and then a newline and log the STDOUT you get and see if it works :)

Comment: Jay - The test case code above does exactly that, doing some standard I/O like any other program would.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem with hanging in stream_get_contents is in the way how process is created.
The correct way is to open STDOUT with read/write mode of pipe, eg:

```
$descriptor = array (0 => array ("pipe", "r"), 1 => array ("pipe", "rw"), 2 => array ("pipe", "rw"));
//Open the resource to execute $command
$t->pref = proc_open($command,$descriptor,$t->pipes);
//Set STDOUT and STDERR to non-blocking 
stream_set_blocking ($t->pipes[0], 0);
stream_set_blocking ($t->pipes[1], 0);
```

This is obvious that when stream_get_contents wants to read the STDOUT pipe it needs read mode.
The same bug with hang/freeze/block is in this nice class https://gist.github.com/Arbow/982320

Then blocking disappears. But read does not read nothing.